# Functions $X\to \mathcal P(X)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$X$ is a set and $f: X \to P(X)$ is a mapping, where $P(X)$ is the power set of $X$. Suppose $Z=\{x \in X: x\notin f(x)\}$, what's correct?

1) $Z$ is empty.

2) $Z$ is nonempty.

3) $Z=X$.

4) $Z$ is in $P(X)$.

5) $Z$ complement is in $P(X)$.

Have no idea for solving the problems.

Comment: Hint: Only 4 and 5 are true.  1,2,3 may or may not hold. Can you construct  $f$'s to breaks each one of them?

Comment: I believe the true answer should be just one of them

Comment: Yes! Awesome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(4) and (5) are obviously true because $Z$ and its complement are subsets of $X$.

(2) may not be true: Let $f:X\to P(X)$ by $f(x)=X$. Even easier, if $X=\varnothing$ then $Z=\varnothing$ for any $f$.

(1),(3) may not be true: Let $X$ be a set with more than one element. Pick $a\in X$. Define $f(x)=\{a\}$ for each $x\in X$.